# SubSonic project history

Tags: subsonic

I'm writing an essay about ORM and SubSonic and I'm looking for some details regarding the project history (initial release, milestones, etc).

Anyone knows where I can find it? anyonce can give me a quick briefing?

Thanks

Comment: @Electric_Monk This is not a programming question, and therefore does not belong on StackOverflow.  Please try migrating this to SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Consipcuous Compiler - this should be on superuser...

That said, check out [the author's blog](http://blog.wekeroad.com/) for some, otherwise you could drop him a note!

Answer (score 1):

You should know that SubSonic started with a different name

> ASP.NET ActionPack

You properbly should find some old blog posts if you search for this name.